# Editing imported content from jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an external Coldfusion page that builds a table based on a query. I then import that external table using jQuery import statement every 10 seconds.

```
$('#container').import('coldfusionTable.cfm').html();
```

There is something I am missing because I can't edit/add functionality to the table. I can't get access the content within the table from jQuery.  There are buttons and such that I want to add functionality to within the table.
I am missing a/many step(s). Please help.

Or at least a place to start reading

Comment: Sorry, but this does not seem to be enough information to help. I don't know about a jQuery `import()` method, so you might be using a plugin. Also, you are missing a closing `'` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to put the javascript in the document being loaded not in the document that it was being loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

If you use methods lie $('td').click() then they won't fire with dynamically loaded data.

Instead, you have to use something like

```
$(document).on('click','td',tdClicked);
function tdClicked() {
}
```